# Does column order matter when creating statistics for Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, statistics

The Database Engine Tuning Advisor has recommended the creation of some statistics for several of our queries.  Turns out that some of these are the same just the column order is different in the CREATE STATISTICS command.  For example:

```
CREATE STATISTICS [StatName1] ON [dbo].[table1]([column2], [column1])

CREATE STATISTICS [StatName2] ON [dbo].[table1]([column1], [column2])
```

are these the same or are they treated differently?

Along the same lines can I combine CREATE STATISTICS command for a given table? If the Advisor recommended 3 different stats on the same column for 3 different queries can I do a single create command for all 3 columns e.g.

```
CREATE STATISTICS [StatName1] ON [dbo].[table1]([column1], [column3])

CREATE STATISTICS [StatName2] ON [dbo].[table1]([column1], [column2])
```

into

```
CREATE STATISTICS [StatName1] ON [dbo].[table1]([column1], [column2], [column3])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

multiple stats on the same column are useless. Only one is needed.
order is irrelevant.

Comment: Why is there a "move up" and "move down" button in the Statistics Properties window in SSMS? Surely not just for cosmetic reasons?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but I am looking to implement something similar.

I am not sure about which version of MS SQL server is being referred in the selected answer; according to the latest documentation, things look different:

As pointed out by @Davos
The order of the columns in the statistics is "very" relevant according to Microsoft documentation. Here is the link to the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/statistics/create-statistics?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(sql13.swb.statistics.propertis.f1)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=sql-server-ver15

Here is an extract from the documentation page:

> Move Up:
> Move the selected column to an earlier location in the statistics grid. The location in the grid can substantially impact the usefulness of the statistics.

Comment: Thanks for taking time and posting your response. If you take a look at the question, it is over 11 years old, so things may have changed. Also, your response is better suited as a comment, since it does not provide a complete answer to the question posted. Consider re-phrasing this as a question with a specific issue and what you have tried to solve it, so the community can have a clearer sense of what you need, and help you solve it. Here are some guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask